# On my MySQL database, I have all privileges on root. However, when I try to set global sql_mode='', I get an error

Tags: mysql, root

So I have a MySQL 8 database and I have my root user having all the permissions. I have flushed as well. But when I try to do a..

```
set global sql_mode='';
```

I get the error of

```
/* SQL Error (1227): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation */
```

I have even went into the mysql program and did the whole granting of *.*. Still nothing.

All I wanted to do was remove strict mode. I even thought perhaps of putting "**sql_mode=''**" into **my.cnf**, but that just caused an issue restarting the service.

Comment: why don't you just restart the machine and try to do the same again ?

Comment: Tried that. Same issue.